# How do I carry a value over in R if a conditional statement is not met

Tags: r, time-series

If Q.gd is less than Q.s times 0.9, then I need to carry the N value that occurred previously in the data frame before Q.gd became less than Q.s times 0.9. If Q.gd is greater than or equal to Q.gd times 0.9, I need to carry the value for N within the corresponding row. Make sense? The new values could be a vector or added to the data frame with the original values. I've been trying to use iterators and foreach for this but am not having any luck. Pasted below is some of the data I'm working with.

```
 datetime      Q.s      Q.gd        Q.run     N
6/16/2013 18:30 24  21.58078484 2.419215163 0.761
6/16/2013 18:45 24  21.5793481  2.420651895 0.788
6/16/2013 19:00 24  21.66973246 2.330267535 0.752
6/16/2013 19:15 24  21.66829    2.331709997 0.797
6/16/2013 19:30 24  21.66684773 2.333152266 0.779
6/16/2013 19:45 24  21.75720822 2.242791777 0.779
6/16/2013 20:00 24  21.75576023 2.244239772 0.788
6/16/2013 20:15 24  21.75431243 2.245687575 0.815
6/16/2013 20:30 25  22.37240843 2.627591566 0.824
6/16/2013 20:45 25  22.46652201 2.533477986 0.743
6/16/2013 21:00 25  22.46502721 2.53497279  0.752
6/16/2013 21:15 24  21.5649913  2.435008699 0.77
6/16/2013 21:30 24  21.56355667 2.436443328 0.788
6/16/2013 21:45 24  21.92913708 2.070862921 0.797
6/16/2013 22:00 24  21.7441832  2.255816798 0.806
6/16/2013 22:15 24  21.55925393 2.440746073 0.779
6/16/2013 22:30 24  21.83302627 2.166973725 0.806
6/16/2013 22:45 24  21.9233036  2.0766964   0.797
6/16/2013 23:00 24  21.92184572 2.078154285 0.815
6/16/2013 23:15 24  21.82867092 2.17132908  0.806
6/16/2013 23:30 24  22.01064153 1.989358466 0.842
6/16/2013 23:45 24  21.91747322 2.082526776 0.833
6/17/2013 0:00  24  22.00771493 1.992285073 0.842
6/17/2013 0:15  24  22.18963735 1.810362652 0.815
6/17/2013 0:30  24  22.0047891  1.995210902 0.814
6/17/2013 0:45  24  22.095007   1.904992998 0.814
6/17/2013 1:00  24  22.00186405 1.998135953 0.832
6/17/2013 1:15  24  22.09207015 1.907929846 0.814
6/17/2013 1:30  24  21.90727752 2.092722476 0.814
6/17/2013 1:45  24  21.90582177 2.09417823  0.805
6/17/2013 2:00  24  21.99601628 2.003983723 0.805
6/17/2013 2:15  24  22.0861988  1.913801201 0.796
6/17/2013 2:30  24  22.08473145 1.915268552 0.823
6/17/2013 2:45  24  22.2665279  1.733472105 0.823
6/17/2013 3:00  24  22.17342305 1.826576955 0.787
6/17/2013 3:15  24  22.08033056 1.919669436 0.814
6/17/2013 3:30  24  22.07886399 1.921136008 0.778
6/17/2013 3:45  24  22.35221999 1.647780008 0.85
6/17/2013 4:00  24  22.35073556 1.649264441 0.85
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sample data seems unnecessarily large. It would also be helpful if you supplied the desired output for the sample data. Perhaps you could clearly show where the break points you are interested in occur. If your code partially worked but failed under certain conditions, it would be nice to share and identify the failings. What you are doing is hardly "standard." It's better to update the question to show more effort rather than just sounding like asking someone else to do the hard work.

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

> crit <- ifelse (df$Q.gd < 0.9*df$Q.s, NA, df$N)
>   crit_new <- na.locf(crit, na.rm = FALSE)

Setting na.rm to FALSE kept the vector the same length as the data frame, allowing me to use cbind() to put the data back in the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
# create a vector that keeps the current N if Q.gd is greater than or equal to Q.gd, NA otherwise
crit <- ifelse(df$Q.gd < 0.9*df$Q.s, NA, df$N)
crit

# fill in the missing values of crit with the last non-missing value of crit
newN <- crit
for (i in 2:length(crit)) {
    if (is.na(crit[i])) newN[i] <- last else last <- crit[i]
    }
newN
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I couldn't get that code to work. I ended up using na.locf() in zoo.